# WTForms Form has changed

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

In my view code,

I build the form using the following line:

```
MyForm(obj=my_obj)
```

The post method would rebuild the form using:

```
UserAccountForm(request.form)
```

How would you check if some form attribute has changed when writting an update form ?

Answer (score 1):

I could have compared it the to database value but I was unable to do that.

The attribute I wanted to know has changed, was the key of all other attributes in my NoSQL database.

There for I added a signed hidden field to the form that, I could compare when posting the form to the value in the visible form.

Comment: Have you added hidden field dynamically?